# How to correctly assign elements of recursively typed collections?

Tags: python, python-3.x, mypy, recursive-type

According to https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/731 recursive type definition should be possible and enabled by default. And for me it's working somehow.

However I didn't manage to successfully assign a value from a recursively typed list, without `mypy` complaining:

```py
from typing import Union  # need this, because strings cannot be `or`-ed

NestedStringSequence = list[Union[str, "NestedStringSequence"]]

element: NestedStringSequence = []
stack: NestedStringSequence = [element]

stack.append([])
element = stack.pop()
```

So `element` should be `str` or `NestedStringSequence`, yet `mypy` gives me

```bash
$ mypy nested.py
nested.py:10: error: Incompatible types in assignment (expression has type "Union[str, NestedStringSequence]", variable has type "NestedStringSequence")  [assignment]
Found 1 error in 1 file (checked 1 source file)
```

.. which sounds like a contradiction to me because `NestedStringSequence` *is* by definition `Union[str, NestedStringSequence]`

But of course it's not a contradiction - `stack.pop()` could return a `str`, and only I know that I'm only `append`ing lists..

How should I deal with this? I could `cast` the result of `stack.pop()` of course, but that would be cheating, wouldn't it?

The answer to a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49101404/1668622) suggests `@overload`ing, but I guess that would imply somehow wrapping `list.pop()`, which would be even uglier in my eyes..

I'm using `mypy` 1.2.0

Answer (score 1):

Ok, after explaining my problem well enough I figured out I just had to type `stack` differently to be a `list` of `NestedStringSequence` (which it actually *is*, of course)..

```py
from typing import Union

NestedStringSequence = list[Union[str, "NestedStringSequence"]]

element: NestedStringSequence = []
stack: list[NestedStringSequence] = [element]

stack.append([])
element = stack.pop()
```